# Send 2 PHP variables to JavaScript and save them in 2 JavaScript variables using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 2 variables in my PHP file ($name , $size) and want to send them to JavaScript and save their values in 2 JavaScript variables (name , size) using AJAX.

This is my PHP code:

```
          <?php

               $sql = "SELECT TOP 1 name , size FROM dbo.server";
               $mmt = sqlsrv_query( $connec, $sql );

               if( $mmt === false )  
         {  
               echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";  
               die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
         }  

               $name = sqlsrv_get_field( $mmt, 0);
               $size = sqlsrv_get_field( $mmt, 1);

               
                $return_arr[] = array (
                       "name" => $name,
                       "size" => $size);


                $myJSON = json_encode($return_arr);

                echo $myJSON;

               sqlsrv_free_stmt( $mmt);  
               sqlsrv_close( $connec);  

         ?>
```

This is my AJAX code. Can anybody help me to include my PHP variables ($name and $size) in AJAX.

```
            ajax_call = function() {
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test.php",
                dataType: "json",
                     success: function (response) {
                     size = response;
                     console.log(size);
                });
               };
                var interval = 5000;
                setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
               });
```

Comment: What is the issue? Getting some error or unexpected results?

Comment: @NotABot Actually I don't know how to call my 2 PHP variables ($name and $size) in AJAX.

Comment: Anything you are getting in ``console``? Also, **echo** ``$name`` and ``$size``, in the same statement, don't use two **echo's**.  You can try something like this, ``$dataToSend = array("name" => $name, "size" => $size); ``, and then ``echo json_encode($dataToSend)``;

Comment: @NotABot Thanks, it is not showing anything in my console. Do you know how I can call PHP variables in the AJAX?

Comment: Does the ``console.log()`` shows empty data, or undefined or null?? Also, check-in your PHP file that you are getting the correct data in those two ``$name`` and ``$size`` variables?

Comment: @NotABot It is showing empty data. My PHP file is ok, I think the reason I am not getting any result is because my AJAX file is not complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224712/discussion-between-not-a-bot-and-coderjay).